# iPhone UIView animation until stop pressing

Tags: iphone, uiview

i have two views and one viewcontroller: one contains UIImageView with image, second have touchesBegan and touchesEnded method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [viewcontroller moveMethod];
}
```

How to make moveMethod method to make the animation (eg. moving the x-axis) repeat smoothly until I stop to push the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code to move your view on x-axis

```
CGRect frame=view.frame;
frame.origin.x=frame.origin.x+200;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];    
view.frame=frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: it works but the animation stops. I'm doing something like this:

    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        [viewcontroller moveMethod];
        viewcontroller.animate = YES;
    }

and in controller:

    - (void)animationFinished:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void*)context {
        if (animate) {
            [self moveMethod];
        }
    }

But then the animation jumps. there are gaps between animations.

Comment: so when do you want to stop animation?

Comment: I press and do not let go of your finger. only when the forest. I have something like this: http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UIView/ but animation jumps between end and start another animation. animation is not continuous.

Comment: (void)animationFinished:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void)context 
{ if (animate) 
{ 
CGRect frame=view.frame;
frame.origin.x=0;//or starting x point
view.frame=frame;
[self moveMethod]; 
}
 }

Comment: yes it works but view stops for a moment before the next animation begins

Comment: if you have set delay parameter,just discard it.

Comment: i found it. [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear]; must be before [UIView setAnimationDuration:...]